# Готовсь или готовьсь?

Tags: орфография

"К сезону готовсь" или "К сезону готовьсь"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, "готовьсь" — это форма "готовься", поэтому мягкий знак стоит после *в*.

Answer (score 5):

**готовьсь!**

Словарь современного русского литературного языка (т. 3 из 20, 1992, стр. 286)

У Ушакова тоже есть. Это сокращение от "готов**ь**ся".

Comment: Alex_ander, Вопрос еще в том, почему возникают сомнения.  Во многих текстах пишется "готовсь", поэтому хорошо бы посмотреть текст нового устава. Возможно, этот вариант взят из устава со старой орфографией?

Comment: Литературная норма и просторечие, Л. И. Скворцов, 1977 с. 107 Таковы формы _равняйсь! Готовьсь!_ (причем более популярна идентичная команда _Товьсь!_)...

Журнал знаменосец за 1983:
_При обучении данным приемам командиры применяют команды: "К бою - ГОТОВЬСЬ", ..._

То же в книге "Основы правоведения" (2000)

Comment: Спасибо! Но вот мне кажется, что в дореволюционных уставах применялась форма "готовсь", поэтому ее до сих пор пытаются оттуда списать.  А у Вас нет ссылки на современный источник (воинский устав), где зафиксирована правильная форма "готовьсь"?

Comment: В Строевом уставе http://www.amurkadet.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Stroevoj-ustav-VS-RF.pdf , где есть множество команд, этой нет вообще. Команда "К бою - готовьсь!" есть во многих пособиях по обучению рукопашному бою, например: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=pOT9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=1dQ-ncLZZw&sig=ACfU3U2Snld_cbyqiBWPHP9oM3Q5em2lCQ&w=1280

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, у нас есть разные уставы, и вот в строевом уставе этой команды нет. Возможное, это "боевая" команда о готовности к стрельбе.